# How can I use an icon instead of a title in the Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm using the Toolbar (instead of ActionBar) via AppCompat. I'd like to replace the Toolbar's title (the app/actity name) with an icon, but I don't see how.

My icon is just text using a non-standard font, so I guess it might be allowed in Material Design.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the following steps in your activity:

1. Declare the Toolbar object:

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool1);
   ```
2. Set the support actionbar:

   ```
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   ```
3. Remove title:

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   ```
4. Add your logo in drawable folder in:

   ```
   res/drawable.
   ```
5. Add logo using this code:

   ```
   toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   ```

Comment: how to set logo dimensions/margin?

Comment: @fnc12 how about  "?attr/actionBarSize" ?

Comment: But what if I want to add another logo? For example, actual logo on the left and an image(image button actually) on the center.

Answer (score 0):

At styles.xml first make a style for action bar with no title and with the logo like that

```
<style name="ActionBar.NoTitle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    </style>
```

Then create custome theme for your activity with new actionbar style

```
<!-- Create a style for MainActivity called AppTheme.Main that uses our custom ActionBar style -->

<style name="AppTheme.Main" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.NoTitle</item>
</style>
```

Then go to manifest file under the specified activity set theme to    AppTheme.Main

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Main"
```

I wish that help everyone

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to a very similar question:
[Android Lollipop, add popup menu from title in toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510930/android-lollipop-add-popup-menu-from-title-in-toolbar/26511653#26511653)

It comes down to using the Toolbar as a ViewGroup (LinearLayout is a ViewGroup too, for instance). The layout designer doesn't currently support that, but you can add a child node in the XML.

Then you need to call this to remove the standard title text:
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: Actually, kunal.c's answer is much better.