# Adding Spinner/Dropdown Menu to Menu Bar in Android 5.0

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I need to add a spinner to the top menu bar in my Android app as seen below:

[image]

Before Android 5.0, I simply used:

```
final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // DEPRACATED
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)
```

but that method was deprecated. I have gone through all the samples at: http://developer.android.com/samples/ui.html but not a single one had a spinner/dropdown menu to base my code off of.

Given NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST is deprecated, how can I add a spinner that will be compatible with Android 5.0, and all the previous versions?

**UPDATE**: After adding the tool bar as can be seen in my code, the error occurs as it notes it cannot see the import even though `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`; is clearly listed

[image]

Comment: Just cast it like this `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need to add a Spinner to the Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You will then need to disable the default title:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// You can then retrieve and setup the Spinner as needed in your Activity/Fragment.
```

From this answer

[Android Lollipop, add popup menu from title in toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510930/android-lollipop-add-popup-menu-from-title-in-toolbar)

Comment: This will not work, if I add ToolBar, it forces the MinSdk version to be 21, not compatible with any previous version. My Android phone, running 4.4, won't even install it

Comment: You need to use the support library. Check the import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: That still does not work. I updated my question as I added the toolbar and view but still has errors, please view

Comment: Take a look at OneWay's comment, you need to cast the View to ToolBar