# How to replace Sherlock ActionBar in with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have an old project in eclipse which uses the Sherlock actionbar, however I would like to replace this actionbar with AppTheme or AppCompat actionbar. I want the actionbar to have the same features such as, dropdown list view. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener,
        OnItemClickListener {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
                R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Lollipop, add popup menu from title in toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510930/android-lollipop-add-popup-menu-from-title-in-toolbar)

Comment: @Maddie_J: please read this two articles.  http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/  and http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-migrating-actionbarsherlock/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) from support design library and AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }

}
```

And add 
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>`

in R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Could you show me how I can change my code to this.